# how to filter Store extjs?

Tags: extjs

I want to filter result from store like below.
I have `textbox` and if I write anything in it then It should filter store accordingly.
e.g. Store result is

```
Monday
Tuesday
Wednesday
Thursday
```

Filter should work like if I type `Mon` then result should be `Monday` only.

I tried below code but no luck.

```
  items: {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        name: 'value',
        width : '100%',
        align: 'center',
        margin: '0 2 2 2',
        listeners : {
             change: function(field, newValue, oldValue, eOpts) {
             var gridRecords = Ext.getCmp('Grid').getStore();
             gridRecords.filter({
                               property: 'value',
                               value: newValue,
                               anyMatch: true,
                               caseSensitive: false
                                               });
                                            }
                                        }
                                      }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you update the rest of your code to show where this fllter is being applied? e.g. the text box event?

Comment: updated code the code

Comment: does the change event definitely fire, can you see what newValue is if you add a breakpoint in?

Comment: what version of extjs are you using?

Comment: sorry one more thing, what does your store config look like, can you share that too please

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ExtJS 4, then you will need to clear the previous filter. As the documentation sates, any filter is applied to the previous filter. So before filtering the store call `gridRecords.clearFilter()`.

Here is a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/peuqda79/) for you to look at.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an object in the filter, pass the values in like so:

```
gridRecords.filter('value',newValue,true,false);
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code will filter the store like you asked and is not case sensitive. You can also type any part of the string like 'es' and the store will filter to show both 'Tuesday' and 'Wednesday'.

```
items: {
  xtype: 'textfield',
  name: 'value',
  width : '100%',
  align: 'center',
  margin: '0 2 2 2',
  listeners : {
    change: function(field, newValue, oldValue, eOpts) {
      var gridRecords = Ext.getCmp('Grid').getStore();
      gridRecords.filterBy(function(record){
        var value = record.get('value').toLowerCase();
        return (value.indexOf(newValue.toLowerCase()) != -1);
      })
    }
  }
}
```